# "So to speak" vs "As it were"

Tags: phrases, differences, word-usage, phrase-usage

As the title says, what is the difference between "so to speak" and "as it were"? Personally, I use them interchangeably but I was wondering if there was a proper way, so to speak (haha), to use the two.

Thanks.

Comment: *as it were, sort of, in a way, so to say, to some extent, in a manner of speaking, in some way or other,...* They're all just "hedges" used by a speaker to avoid sounding too dogmatic about whatever assertion he's making. Personally, I'm more likely to use ***I'd say***. And [here's the evidence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+it+were%2CI%27d+say&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20it%20were%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27d%20say%3B%2Cc0) that my preference is gaining ground even in ***written*** contexts as indexed by Google Books.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases *so to speak* is a cousin to written quote marks (but not necessarily air quotes) signifying a usage that is in some way figurative . *As it were* is *approximately, in a way, roughly speaking*.

There are cases where either may be appropriate—when a word or phrase is being used with a meaning that is not quite canonical. Note that the Collins definition for *as it were* gives *so to speak* as a synonym, so the two expressions clearly overlap.

**so to speak** (idiom)

> Idiom
> Used to indicate that one is using words in an unusual or figurative
> way rather than a literal way [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so%20to%20speak)

> Phrase
> (also so to say)
> Used to highlight the fact that one is
> describing something in an unusual or metaphorical way. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/so_to_speak)
>
> *Delving into the body's secrets, I looked death in the face, so to
> speak.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/so_to_speak)

**as it were** (phrase)

> You say as it were in order to make what you are saying sound less
> definite.
>
> [vagueness]
> *I'd understood the words, but I didn't, as it
> were, understand the question.*
>
> Synonyms: in a way, to some extent, so
> to speak, in a manner of speaking [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/as-it-were)

> In a way (used to be less precise)
>
> *areas that have been, as it were, pushed aside* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/as_it_were)